# Completeness of derivatives of Hilbert basis with respect to a parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let us take a Hilbert basis $\left|x_\lambda\right >$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, i.e. the $\left|x_\lambda\right >$ are a complete, orthonormal set of vectors. The subscript indicates that they depend parametrically on a parameter $\lambda$.

Consider now the new family of vectors $\left|\partial_\lambda x_\lambda\right >$ that is obtained by taking the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ of $\left|x_\lambda\right >$. The notation simply means

$$\left|\partial_\lambda x_\lambda\right >=\sum_i \partial_\lambda\left<i, x_\lambda\right>\left |i \right>$$

with $\left|i\right>$ some fixed, i.e. parameter-independent, basis.

My question: Under what conditions is this new family complete?

To be clear, an example may be the following. The eigenfunctions of the harmonic oscillator hamiltonian are a basis for $L^2(\mathbb C)$, which depends parametrically on the frequency $\omega$ of the oscillator. Are derivatives with respect to $\omega$ of Hermite polynomials times Gaussian still a complete family?

Comment: if $\partial x_i \not \in \mathcal{H}$ then $(\partial x_i)_i$  is clearly not complete.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you have a family $(e_k(t))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of orthonormal bases of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, depending differentiably on a parameter $t\in\mathbb R$. Let us try to decide whether $(e_k'(t_0))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is complete in $\mathcal H$ for some fixed $t_0\in\mathbb R$. For this, we assume that there is a differentiable function $U : \mathbb R\to L(\mathcal H)$ such that $e_k(t) = U(t)e_k$, where $U(t_0) = I$ (the identity operator). This should be the case in your harmonic oscillator example. Obviously, $U(t)$ is a unitary operator for each $t$. Now, if $(e_k'(t))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is not complete, there exists a non-zero vector $x\in\mathcal H$ such that $\langle x,e_k'(t_0)\rangle = 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$. Hence, $0 = \langle x,U'(t_0)e_k\rangle = \langle U'(t_0)^*x,e_k\rangle$ for all $k$, meaning that $U'(t_0)^*x = 0$. Actually, you can remove the star here, since $UU^* = I$ implies $U'U^* + U(U')^* = 0$ and thus $(U')^* = -U^*U'U^*$, which, in $t = t_0$, is $U'(t_0)^* = -U'(t_0)$ (in other words, $U'(t_0)$ is skew symmetric). So, the system $(e_k'(t_0))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is not complete if and only if there exists a non-zero vector in the kernel of $U'(t_0)$.

Comment: I have some kind of physics intuition that the condition that there is no non-zero vector in the kernel of $U'(t)$ is equivalent to the condition that there is no 'direction' in $\mathcal{H}$ which is left invariant under $U(t)$, i.e. $U(t)$ does not have the eigenvalue $1$. Do you think this is true?

Comment: I think my previous comment was ambiguous. What I mean is there is no fixed vector $v$ such that, for all $t$, $U(t)v=v$.